# Why do I see negative average delay in tf_monitor?

Tags: ros, geometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be only when I run simulation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9481/why-do-i-see-negative-average-delay-in-tf_monitor?/) by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Negative average delay comes from the transform being timestamped in the future when sent or by network delays when running in simulation.

In simulation time is sent over the /clock topic and may arrive after transforms sent from a different node with the same time.

A few nodes stamp data in the future, most noteably AMCL. This is valid for AMCL and other similar nodes publishing a small correction transform which is expected to remain approximately static and never have inherent velocity. The value is that AMCL can update at a slow rate but does not prevent transforms through it's correction to be used at a high rate.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0